# Некорректный вывод текста функциями bios

Tags: ассемблер, kernel, ос, bios

Я написал довольно простое ядро, но при выводе второй строки один раз, она выводится два раза. Прошу указать в чем проблема.

```
org 500h                ;this sector adress is 0000:0500h

kmain:
    call scr_clear   
    ;print welcom message:
    mov bp, welcom             
    mov cx, 20
    call term_print     ;print welcom
    call cur_newline    ;new line
    ;print T-DOS>guest>:
    mov bp, ready_no_user
    mov cl, 12
    call term_print

scr_print:
    mov bl,02h
    mov bh,00h
    mov ax,1301h
    int 10h
    ret

term_print:
    call scr_print
    add dl, cl
    mov ah, 2
    int 10h
    mov ax, 0
    ret
cur_newline:
    mov dh, 1
    mov dl, 0
    call cur_setpos
    ret

cur_setpos:
    mov ah, 2
    int 10h
    ret

scr_clear:
    mov ax, 0002h   
    int 10h   
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0
    mov ah, 2
    int 10h
    ret


welcom db 'Welcom to T-DOS 1.0!',0
ready_no_user db 'T-DOS>guest>'
```

Вот текущий вывод на экран (неверный):

```
Welcom to T-DOS 1.0!
T-DOS>guest>T-DOS>guest>_
```

Каким должен быть вывод:

```
Welcom to T-DOS 1.0!
T-DOS>guest>_
```

Comment: А где точка входа? И главное - а где точка выхода?

Comment: после последнего `call term_print` не хватает вечного цикла или останова... иначе весь дальнейший код будет исполняться буквально... возможны и другие ошибки..

Comment: @Fat-Zer Судя по тому, что после второго вывода комп не виснет, после последнего `call term_print` не хватает вульгарного `ret`.

Comment: Забыл добавить ret, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Akina, если это названо гордым словом «ядро», то там должен быть вечный цикл т.к. возвращать управление некому ;)

Comment: @Fat-Zer ну зачем так категорично? возвращаем управление БИОСу, загружается ROM-Basic...

Comment: @ТимМахин Дебаггер где-нить накопайте - в нём можно по одной команде выполнять, и смотреть, куда и почему тебя заносит...

Comment: @Akina, мда... я не на столько стар, что бы знать, что такое когда-то существовало =)